# change the header Content-Type to application/cloudevents+json when publishing to event grid

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using the trigger "When a HTTP request is received" to then publish multiple events to the event grid using the "Publish Event" action. The For loop works fine to split up the JSON that gets in and create the event to publish but still that publish fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnsupportedMediaType",
    "message": "The Content-Type header is either missing or it doesn't have a valid value. The content type header must either be application/cloudevents+json; charset=utf-8 or application/cloudevents-batch+json; charset=UTF-8. Report 'edf36bbd-9221-4882-8a29-2264ffb16d72:3:3/6/2020 2:18:20 PM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidContentType",
        "message": "The Content-Type header is either missing or it doesn't have a valid value. The content type header must either be application/cloudevents+json; charset=utf-8 or application/cloudevents-batch+json; charset=UTF-8. Report 'edf36bbd-9221-4882-8a29-2264ffb16d72:3:3/6/2020 2:18:20 PM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I assume that the header from the input is used when publishing so I tried to change the header when publishing by changing the header in the Publish_Event block as follows (directly in code view as it is not supported in the UI) so I get the following (headers part is added):

```
"Publish_Event": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": [
            {
                "data": "@items('For_each_2')",
                "eventType": "company-location",
                "id": "ID : @{items('For_each')['businessId']}",
                "subject": "Company Location changed"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/cloudevents+json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgridpublish']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/eventGrid/api/events"
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

But this is not working neither. Didn't find an action to make the change.

My full flow looks like this : [image: app logic flow]

and as test data I have the following JSON I use to send with postman (a bit simplified):

```
[
    {
        "id": 3603,
        "businessId": "QQTADOSH",
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 5316,
                "businessId": "A-yelr3g"
            },
            {
                "id": 5127,
                "businessId": "A-c7i8gd"
            },
            {
                "id": 5403,
                "businessId": "A-fjdd2y"
            },
            {
                "id": 6064,
                "businessId": "A-rqvhz8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3118,
        "businessId": "Cr11_Macan_111qa",
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 4563,
                "businessId": "A-3bv860"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen, could you please provide a data sample which you input to the "Publish Event" action, then I can use your data as hard code to test. I test it by some simple data and it works fine.

Comment: Added it to the ticket. Simplified the input but still got the same InvalidContentType error. The raw output of the publish event does contain "Content-Type": "application/json" but I don't see where I can change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [Official Event Grid Publish Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureeventgridpublish/) doesn't support [Cloud Events Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema).

You can set the topic to accept [Event Grid Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema) but I believe this is possible only at the time of creation.

Its best to open a [feature request on UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to add support for this and in the meantime, a workaround would be to use an [HTTP Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action) to [Post to Custom Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic) instead.

**But** do note that the workaround would involve building the event payload to send (and things like fetching the access key [from Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/keyvault/) instead of storing it in your workflow directly).

Comment: Indeed retested with event grid schema and that worked fine. Thx for the info

Comment: Added the feature request : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/39894421-cloud-events-schema-support-when-posting-to-event